# How to avoid to_char() cast in concatenation oracle?

Tags: oracle, concatenation

How to avoid to_char() cast with formatting fractional value to avoid possible errors in future depending on input values? e.g.

```
SELECT -0.56 || 'value' FROM DUAL;
```

will return

> -.56value

and I would like to have

> -0.56value.

I know that I can use

```
select to_char(-0.56, '990.00') || 'value' from dual;
```

But I don't know how many digits can be in the future

Comment: See the documentation on to_char here:- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm '0.00' will give you leading zeroes and 2 decimal places, but it isn't clear if this is what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char(-0.56, '999999990.00')` with enough 9's to cover all your possible values. (There is always a limit, since the NUMBER data type is at most 38 digits - and yes, you could have 37 9's and a 0 in the format model.)

This may add some unwanted spaces to the left; to modify that behavior, use the `fm` modifier: `to_char(-0.56, 'fm99999999990.00')`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select rtrim(to_char(-0.56, 'FM9999999990.999999999'), '.') || 'value' from dual;
```

Comment: The OP explicitly had '....0.00.....' in the format model, meaning they want at least two decimal places. If so, then '...0.99999' is not what is needed. With the two decimal places, there is never a need to trim the decimal point either.